# WPF binding to combobox in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

I have a class in a WPF MVVM application which I would like to display in a popup form and manage some of its members.

```
public class Route
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RouteSegment> MandatorySegments { get; set; }
}

public class RouteSegment
{
   public decimal Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've only added a few of the member fields, the rest are not relevant.

What I would like to do is to display all the items found in `MandatorySegments` list in a combobx in a datagrid so I can add and remove new members easily.

This is the code I have so far:

In my ViewModel

```
public RouteTest SelectedRoute { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<RouteSegment> AllRouteSegments { get; private set; }
public RouteSegment SelectedMandatorySegment { get; set; }
```

In my View

```
<DataGrid Grid.RowSpan="2"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,6,0,5" Name="dgMandatorySegments" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="306"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRouteTest.MandatorySegments, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                      CanUserAddRows="{StaticResource False}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMandatorySegment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Route Segment">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AllRouteSegments, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CboxItemTemplate}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

What I'm missing is the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` on the combobox in the templated grid column. Now, in the grid I have the same number of rows as elements in my list and the `ItemsSource` of the combobox binds properly, because I can choose from all the `RouteSegment` elements. But the initial value is always empty for all the rows in the datagrid.
What should the `SelectedValue` of the combobox bind to?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you want the same default value for all rows - or row-independent initial values. I would recommend you use the `SelectedItem` to avoid issues with `SelectedValue` not working reliably. The current VM you have only allows for one selected mandatory segment - given this assumption, you are only setup for one default value for all grid rows.

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AllRouteSegments, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMandatorySegment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"                                               
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CboxItemTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: I want row independent values for all rows. The combobox items source has 100 items for example, but my `Route.MandatorySegments` has only 5 items. So each row in the datagrid will contain a combobox with its initial value set for each of these 5 items respectively.
I will try your implementation, thanks.

Comment: Using `DataContext.SelectedMandatorySegment` does not work. Do I maybe need to wrap the elements of `DataContext.AllRouteSegments` somehow? How does every row know how to bind to each of the elements in `Route.MandatorySegments` ?

Comment: Do you assign `SelectedMandatorySegment` a default value in the ctor? `SelectedMandatorySegment` should also implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) to see any updates in the UI.

Comment: No, I don't assign an initial value to `SelectedMandatorySegment`. I use this variable to have access to the selected row in the grid (So i can display some extra information in a different panel).
As you can see from the way the classes are defined, I need to bind the `SelectedItem` of the combobox to the members of `List<RouteSegment> MandatorySegments`. This is what I'm having trouble with..

Answer (score 0):

**DisplayMemberPath** is probably what you want. The following ComboBox works nicely in a DataGrid in my WPF application. (Please note that you need to update the binding path to make it work in your application.)

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllRouteSegments}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMandatorySegment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```